# How to solve cordova emulate android issue?

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have unistalled Java 12 and installed Java 8, but cordova emulate android doesn't work...
How can I solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about changing `JAVA_HOME` to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home`?

When it can find the JDK, it should also find `javac`.

Comment: Where can I find JAVA_HOME?